# Foxit Reader - How to get rid of the feature advertisement box, which interferes with scrolling?

Tags: spam-prevention, advertisements, foxit-reader

Just above the scroll bar, there is a rectangular area that I am constantly accidentally hitting, which expands when you place your mouse over it, blocking you from being able to press the top arrow of the scroll bar, until you move your mouse completely away from where you need to put your mouse pointer, in order for the box to disappear again, so you can VERY CAREFULLY move your mouse up to that tiny arrow.  A couple of minutes ago it was advertising 'convert PDF to Excel - try it now for free,' and now it's saying 'convert PDF to Word.'

How do permanently remove that box?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a checkbox to disable advertisements, near the bottom of the preferences section. Unchecking it removes that box, and the problem along with it.